# SASS: Proper way to target descendants based on page class

Tags: sass

This one got me stuck.

I want to add a background image to #page-title based on the body class.

I was sass to compile to:

```
body.front #page-title {
background-image: url('front.png');
}

body.blog #page-title {
background-image: url('blog.png');
}
```

Obviously the real code is more complex (and the actual will contain background-position and not a distinct image) but you get the idea. Each of the elements in the tree already has significant styling.

What is the best way to make this happen?

Thanks much!

EDIT: Well, I found a solution which works:

```
body {
/* body attributes */

#page-title { 
/* #page-title attributes */
}

 &.front #page-title {
 /* body.front #page-title attributes */
 }

 &.blog #page-title {
 /* body.blog #page-title attributes */
 }
}
```

This renders properly, but reentering #page-title after each page class just feels wrong. Somehow I wonder if I'm not yielding to the sass way, but until I have a better solution (@import?), this works.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're answering your own question, actually submit an answer.  Don't just modify your question.

Answer (score 2):

I would simplify the CSS before writing the SASS.

Assuming .blog and .front are the only classes you are using for body, then you have one too many classes. Why not set a default class (.blog) and then add a selector for .front?

```
body #page-title {
    background-image: url('blog.png');
}

body.front #page-title {
    background-image: url('front.png');
}
```

Alternatively, you could set the default value and then add the class to the #page-title element.

```
#page-title {
    background-image: url('blog.png');
}

#page-title.front {
    background-image: url('front.png');
}
```